# Is there a Biblical reason why the church of Christ does not use instrumental music?

Tags: biblical-basis, worship, music, psalms

I have heard all of my life that the New Testament does not authorize the use of musical instruments, so the church of Christ does not use them.  They say they are silent where the Bible is silent, and they speak where the Bible speaks.

But, David used musical instruments.  Psa. 33:2,

> "Praise the Lord with the harp;
>       make music to him on the ten-stringed lyre."  (NIV)

Or, as in Psa. 81:2-3,

> "2 Take a psalm, and bring hither the timbrel, the pleasant harp with the psaltery.
>
> 3 Blow up the trumpet in the new moon, in the time appointed, on our solemn feast day."  (KJV)

Is there a Biblical explanation for not using instruments of music under the New Testament?